# Is there any other method to do curve fitting on python except scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I made an code, fitting data to sin graph. but it didn't made well.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def f(x, a, b, c, d):
    return (a)*np.sin((b)*x+(c))+(d)

df = pd.read_csv("./data.csv", usecols = ['t3','Vz'])

#df=pd.read_csv("E:/2023/spring/프밍기/codes/data.csv")
data_need = df.iloc[range(249), [0, 1]]
x = np.array(data_need['t3'])
y = np.array(data_need['Vz'])

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y)

a, b, c, d = popt
formatted_a = "{:.3f}".format(a)
formatted_b = "{:.3f}".format(b)
formatted_c = "{:.3f}".format(c)
formatted_d = "{:.3f}".format(d)
function_expression = f"y = {formatted_a} * sin({formatted_b}x + {formatted_c}) + {formatted_d}"
print(function_expression)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='.')
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x, f(x, *popt), color='red', linewidth=2)
plt.legend(['Original', 'Best Fit'], loc=2)
plt.show()
```

the output was like below:
[image: not good]
I want to know why the result is not good, and is there are any other method to make a curve fitting in python.

Comment: You can search for package in the Python Package Index: https://pypi.org/

Comment: The thick blue horizontal line at the left side of the plot probably indicates that a lot of points are near zero, so your data probably isn't really a sin function.
Try creating some synthetic data first to check that fitting works.

Comment: You will hardly be able to fit a single function for all points... The behavior of the data up to approximately x = 2.5 is completely different from the data for x > 2.5....

Comment: Tip: Since your data is trending periodically, try using only a portion of the data to fit the function... Choose a portion of the data that comprises two peaks (a maximum and a minimum)... Example: from x = 4 to x = 6... or from x = 7 to x = 10 (approximately)

Comment: [`lmfit`](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) is very good.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple packages to do various fit and/or modelling tasks.

A characteristic feature of any curve fitting / least squares minimization is that you need to supply an initial guess for the parameters. If the initial guess is very off, minimization may not converge at all, or convergence to a suboptimal solution.

In this case, you did not specify an initial guess, and `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` used some values and the result is bad; so the first thing to do is to specify it. You can crudely estimate the amplitude from the data range, the frequency from the peak-to-peak distance etc.

And remove that zero patch in the beginning of the data stream.

Comment: _If the initial guess is very off, minimization may not converge at all, or convergence to a suboptimal solution_ is true for generic fitting methods; but generic fitting methods are very ill-suited to this application. Use an FFT and no initial guess is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# It's just a dummy data...
n = 200
xdata = np.linspace(0, 25, n)

ydata = np.array([3.38, 2.811, 2.539, 1.925, 1.717, 1.529, 1.185, 1.035, 
                  1.191, 1.272, 1.238, 1.477, 1.821, 2.102, 2.142, 2.528, 
                  2.813, 3.594, 3.542, 3.717, 3.918, 4.165, 3.965, 3.547, 
                  3.651, 3.262, 2.694, 2.324, 2.014, 1.589, 1.263, 1.288, 
                  1.132, 0.832, 0.881, 1.075, 1.298, 1.491, 1.919, 2.55, 
                  2.556, 3.061, 3.33, 3.415, 3.751, 3.906, 4.239, 3.735, 
                  3.793, 3.655, 3.457, 3.045, 2.427, 2.192, 1.584, 1.468, 
                  1.344, 1.264, 1.09, 0.78, 1.145, 1.226, 1.502, 1.989, 
                  2.223, 2.6, 2.896, 3.5, 3.651, 3.864, 4.023, 4.074, 3.993, 
                  4.001, 3.292, 2.983, 2.673, 2.728, 2.157, 1.745, 1.538, 
                  0.988, 0.923, 1.094, 1.103, 1.15, 1.172, 1.687, 1.884, 
                  2.256, 2.927, 3.21, 3.424, 3.734, 3.8, 3.849, 3.865, 4.097, 
                  3.639, 3.644, 3.472, 2.945, 2.46, 2.24, 1.808, 1.427, 1.043, 
                  0.861, 0.862, 0.968, 1.278, 1.406, 1.552, 1.853, 2.117, 
                  2.489, 3.186, 3.153, 3.82, 3.617, 4.127, 3.919, 4.153, 
                  3.893, 3.294, 3.145, 2.759, 2.619, 1.887, 1.673, 1.675, 
                  1.149, 1.213, 0.853, 0.898, 1.38, 1.484, 1.764, 1.895, 
                  2.388, 2.602, 3.156, 3.297, 3.622, 3.846, 3.772, 3.891, 
                  3.912, 3.88, 3.4, 3.457, 2.773, 2.307, 1.991, 1.666, 1.312, 
                  0.999, 1.118, 1.015, 1.242, 0.921, 1.128, 1.387, 1.942, 
                  2.096, 2.739, 2.875, 3.286, 3.776, 4.09, 3.948, 3.86, 4.099, 
                  3.756, 3.735, 3.182, 3.066, 2.27, 2.163, 1.623, 1.604, 
                  1.375, 1.3, 0.968, 1.098, 0.888, 1.363, 1.445, 1.82, 2.214, 
                  2.747, 2.902, 3.502, 3.766, 3.691, 3.74, 3.946, 3.999, 
                  3.629, 3.629])


def f(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a*np.sin(b*x + c) + d

# fitting all data
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata)
a, b, c, d = popt

# using only a portion of the data
i = slice(0, 25)
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(f, xdata[i], ydata[i])
a2, b2, c2, d2 = popt2

print(popt)
print(popt2)

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, marker='.', ls='')
plt.plot(xdata, f(xdata, *popt), color='red', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(xdata, f(xdata, *popt2), color='orange', linewidth=2)
plt.legend(['Original', 
            f'Fitting all data ({n} points)', 
            f'Fitting from i = {i.start} to {i.stop-1}'], 
           loc=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Curve fitting for a sine is prone to failure, so don't even try it. Do an FFT and observe the peak instead. Do an `rfft` from Numpy. It will be more robust and doesn't need bounds or an initial guess to work well. It even works (basically) fine with your zero section, though it will be better without it:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng


fsample = 10
tend = 25


def synthesize(f: float = 0.4) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    tstart = 2.5
    istart = int(tstart*fsample)
    phase = np.pi*0.7
    rand = default_rng(seed=0)

    t3 = np.arange(0, tend, 1/fsample)
    Vz = np.zeros_like(t3)

    Vz[istart:] = 0.4*np.sin(
        2*np.pi*f * t3[istart:]
        + phase
    ) + rand.normal(scale=0.02, size=t3.size - istart)

    return t3, Vz


def fit(Vz: np.ndarray) -> tuple[float, float, float]:
    spectrum = np.fft.rfft(Vz)
    power = abs(spectrum)
    ipeak = power.argmax()
    phase = np.angle(spectrum[ipeak])
    freq = ipeak * fsample / Vz.size
    return freq, power[ipeak], phase


def reconstruct(freq: float, power: float, phase: float) -> np.ndarray:
    n = tend*fsample
    spectrum = np.zeros(shape=1 + n//2, dtype=np.complex128)
    ipeak = int(freq * n // fsample)
    spectrum[ipeak] = power*(np.cos(phase) + 1j*np.sin(phase))
    Vz = np.fft.irfft(spectrum)
    return Vz


def plot(t3: np.ndarray, Vz: np.ndarray, Vz_fit: np.ndarray, title: str) -> None:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(t3, Vz, label='experiment')
    ax.plot(t3, Vz_fit, label='fft reconstruct')
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()


def main() -> None:
    t, Vz = synthesize()
    freq, power, phase = fit(Vz)
    ampl = 2*power/Vz.size
    Vz_fit = reconstruct(freq, power, phase)
    plot(
        t, Vz, Vz_fit,
        title=f'Vz ~ {ampl:.2f}sin(2pi*{freq:.2f}t + {phase:.3f})',
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: fft reconstruct]